# Cox interactions and co-linearity

Tags: interaction, cox-model, multicollinearity

I am interested in developing a model to predict survival based on a few predictors: age, sex, and two lab values, albumin and globulin. 
I have approximately 14,000 deaths in the data. 
I initially looked at albumin and created separate models for men and women. I used restricted cubic splines for both the albumin term and the age term and allowed them to interact. I obtained very interesting results. Now, I am trying to incorporate a related lab test - globulin - and the ratio of albumin to globulin in a more comprehensive model. 
 The issue I am having is that albumin is that both albumin and globulin are correlated with the ratio (obviously). Age is correlated with albumin but not the globulin or ratio. 
How should I go about further exploring and/or structuring/evaluating a model to achieve the best predictive accuracy?